# Image doesn't grow in width to equal parent div's width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a really simple page, with a div. Inside that div is an image that sits at the top of the div some text that sits below the image.

**My Problem:** The image is supposed to have a width equal to the divs width, ie, the image is supposed to stretch to the width of the div. But what happens is that the image stretches only about 80% of the width of the div, so theres a gap on the right side of the image.

How can I make the image stretch all the way to the right so its width is the same as the divs width? I think you can see my problem in JSFiddle(complete with uploaded images): http://jsfiddle.net/ajEmm/ *but I also encourage you to show the HTML in IE, the image is a link so it will show.*

**NOTE: This problem only occurs in IE, in firefox the image correctly stretches to the width of the div**

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    <!--
        body        { background-color: RGB(218,238,248); }

        .content      { padding-top: 2%; margin: 10px; margin-top: 0; width: 58%;
                        max-width: 58%; float: left; color: #454545; }

        #announcement { margin: 5%; margin-top: 0%; margin-bottom: 5%; border-color: #99CCFF;
                        border-width:thin; border-style:solid; border-right-width:thick;
                        border-top-width:0px; border-bottom-width:thick; background-color: #FFFFFF; }
    -->
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="content">
        <div id="announcement">
            <img class="anncHeading" src="http://i54.tinypic.com/qs1lsg.png" width="100%" height="60%" alt="1"/>
            <p><b>Announcements</b></p>
            <p>Planning on hosting an indoor/outdoor event? We have large, modern educational facilities & surounding gardens available for hire & lease at an economical rate.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Woah, woah woah.

- **PLEASE** write it in a structured, easy-to-digest format. It will help you out in the long run as you learn code (whether it's css, php, js, etc...)
- Your code is formatted poorly. I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ajEmm/3/ (plugged everything in the HTML box so you can just copy and paste it into your page file)
- Because some users have *massive* screen resolutions, `width: 58%;` could be **incredibly large**. Using a percentage-based width like that is good practice, but usually reserved for site containers and core elements. *When using images in fluid layouts*, special precautions must be taken (to avoid warping, etc). In your specific case, the image you have IS NOT IDEAL for the code you have. I would suggest one of two things:

  1. Set the container width at `450px`, which is the width of your image; or,
  2. Rewrite the way your page works, and use a really long header image without text. If you would like to do this, I'm available to help you. Let me know and I'll make a fiddle and write instructions for ya. :)

Comment: Do you mean the HTML is hard to read or the CSS is hard to read? Or both?

Comment: The CSS is hard to read. Each property should be on a new line.

Comment: I updated my answer. OP, I included the `img { width: 100%; }` that I had before in the jsfiddle update (see answer, above). However, I think that your development of the page could be approached differently.